# sort checkbox values in javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, forms

I need to have all the values of checked checkboxes sorted with commas in javascript, so I can send the to a form sending php script.

The javascript:

```
var services = [];
$('#field-services:checked').each(function() {
services.push($(this).val());
});

$.post(rootUrl+'/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php', { action:"two2_send_contact_form", services:services }
```

I have the checkboxes inside a div with the id `field-services`
the php that send the email

```
$services = $_POST["services"];
$subject = "BLAH BLAH";
    $body = "Services: $services, \n\n$message";
```

Comment: jquery I presume? Probably an important tag...

Comment: doesnt seem like the case, everything else works perfect, and dreamweaver didnt detect anything. i'll double check anyway thanks

Comment: I'm saying, you didn't tell us what javascript library you're using. Your question tags don't include "jquery". That seems more important than "checkbox".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$('#field-services:checked')` of course won't work, because id must be unique so there must be only one `#field-services` checked. You probably want to do:

```
var services = []
$('#field-services input:checked').each(function(){
  services.push(this.value)
})
```

Comment: i tried this, and the result i got in the email was: "Array, "what i was getting before was simply " , ". i'm not sure how the "Array" got in there

Comment: Arrays become 'Array' when you cast them to a string. Try using `implode(', ',$services)` in the email.

Comment: THANK YOU! that worked. should've thought of that. i actually saw it on another unrelated question and thought that wont be it. thanks man.